# Javascript window location refreshes page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the window url using `window.location` but it seemes like it doesn't work.

```
function redirect() {
  var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to log out ?');
  if (r) {

    window.location.href = "http://localhost/mypage.php";
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("failed");
    return false;
  }
}
```

When i press ok, the page refreshes..

Comment: Where are you calling `redirect()` from?  What *do* want it to do when you press OK?

Comment: To refresh your page you can simply do: `location.reload();`

Comment: This is the correct behavior . It should redirected to http://localhost/mypage.php

Comment: Worth a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: It's called from a button onclick="redirect()"

Comment: Ok .... maybe i expressed myself wrong. I want it to redirect , not to refresh

Comment: i think it should working fine. check the path again.

Answer (score 0):

window.history.pushState('AnotherPage', 'title', '/pageUrl');

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. I have tested it and work fine. Check your others scripts maybe some interference.

> !IMPORTANT! Check also if your trigger button is not submit type ...
>   if is submit type not working ... So if is this your problem must
>   manipulate the button type to button inside your function.

```
... if (r) {
  document.getElementById('your_button').setAttribute("type", "button");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **window.location**:

```
function redirect() {
  var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to log out ?');
  if (r) {

    window.location = "http://localhost/mypage.php";
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("failed");
    return false;
  }
}
```

call it on `onclick="redirect();"` in button.

See example here : [Javascript Page Redirect](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_page_redirect.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The redirect should work fine with the following code (without the need for href):

```
window.location = "http://localhost/mypage.php";
```

Another thing to check is that the redirect URL is pointing to the correct location i.e. are there any subdirectories that need to be included in the path? e.g. "http://localhost/folder/mypage.php"?